# Spresense+VSCodeでSDKのalamのビルドが出来ない

Tags: spresense, vscode

下記開発環境で、実行内容の5を実行したところ、実行結果にある様にtools/Makefile.unix:236でエラーがあるとと出てきてしまい先に進めません。このファイルはこちらで作った物ではなく困ってます。

よろしくお願いします。

#### 開発環境

Windows10
VSCodeバージョン: 1.66.1 (user setup)
SDKバージョン：2.5

#### 実行内容

1. アプリケーションフォルダを右クリックしてSpresense: SDKコンフィグを開く
2. 新規作成をクリック
3. Examplesタブ -> alarm を選択して、OKをクリックする
4. 保存をクリックしてコンフィグレーションを保存する
5. アプリケーションフォルダを右クリックしてSpresense: ビルドと書き込みを実行する

#### 実行結果

```
make[1]: *** [tools/Makefile.unix:236: include/nuttx/version.h] エラー 1 make[1]: ディレクトリ '/c/msys64/home/0000960141/spresense/nuttx' から出ます make: *** [Makefile:114: all] エラー 2 ターミナル プロセス "c:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe '-c', '.vscode/build.sh build'" が終了コード 2 で終了しました。
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

理由は分かりませんが、Makefile の依存関係ファイルが壊れているようです

```
Make.dep:1514: 警告: NUL 文字があります; 行の残りは無視されます
Make.dep:1515: 警告: NUL 文字があります; 行の残りは無視されます
Make.dep:1516: 警告: NUL 文字があります; 行の残りは無視されます
Make.dep:1517: *** 分離記号を欠いています. 中止.
```

[https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_ターミナルを使用したspresense_sdkの操作方法](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html#_%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fspresense_sdk%E3%81%AE%E6%93%8D%E4%BD%9C%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95) `6.4.2 Spresense SDKをクリーンアップする` を参考に、一旦ターミナルを開いて、`sdk`フォルダ上で`make distclean` を実行してみてください。

その後で改めて実行内容の1.から開始してみるとうまくいくかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。やってみます。

Comment: 同じエラーになってしまうのでSDKを再インストールしてやってみます。

Comment: spresense関連フォルダの再インストールからでも駄目だったので、MSYSのアンインストールで更地に戻してやったら出来ました。